# PHP Soap Client to handle multipart/related

Tags: php, soap, download, soapui, soap-client

I am developing an application that needs to access a SOAP api. The soap API should return a base64 encoded zip file, and it does so when being fired from SOAPUI. However I am trying to read this result programatically therefore I would need to get the file with a request fired from PHP.

```
        $client = new MTOMSoapClient($url, array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,"trace" => 1));

        $user_param = array (
            'DealerCode' => "1234",
            'Hash' => "asjdfasjda1231231231",
            'Password' => "somerandompassword",
            'UserName' => "somerandomusername"
        );

        var_dump(
            $client->__soapCall(
                "DownloadOffer",
                array($user_param)
            )
        );

        var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
```

I also extended PHP's soap client like shown here without the proper results: https://gist.github.com/pkmishra/2243055

The same error is shown in postman:

`SoapFault: Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'multipart/related; type=&quot;application/xop+xml&quot;'. in file /app/app/Http/Middleware/MTOMSoapClient.php on line 8`

Any advice, library, way to get the response or at least the reason behind the error is greatly apreciated.

Comment: Can you share a working SOAPUI post?

Comment: sadly no. It's a private API.

Comment: You said you managed to make it work using SOAPUI?

Comment: Yes, I also managed to make it pass this error by using "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,

Comment: Now i'm getting ```SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from: <> failed to load external entity```

Comment: You don't need a soapclient, see https://vedovini.net/2009/08/13/posting-multipart-form-data-using-php/ and https://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments/.